# Uncaught ReferenceError: eve is not defined

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Snap svg is quite new to me, I have followed the setup mentioned in the https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg. (webpack setup) But I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: eve is not defined".

So I ended up using "const Snap = require(`imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0!snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js`);" for production, but this not working for the unit test.

Error is from this line`eve = function (name, scope) {` in "snap.svg.js".

Comment: where are declaring `eve`

Comment: Im not declaring eve, its from snap svg package in node_modules.

Comment: Am I having the same issue but with a Preact app.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a webpack config setup issue:

```json
{
    test: require.resolve('snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js'),
    use: 'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0',
}
```

These lines should be at top of the rules(first element of the rules array) in webpack config module object.